System is attempting to load a plugin, but detected an incorrect plugin type
in my code i got an error [Err] [gazebo_shared.cc:46] System is attempting to load a plugin, but detected an incorrect plugin type. Plugin filename[libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so]. I am using gazebo11 on RoS2 Humble. I have made the apt changes to the URDF files, CMake file, packages.xml file and the launch files to no avail. I tried using ultrasonic sensors but then switched. Most online resources are failing.


  <gazebo reference="sensor_link">
  <sensor type="ray" name="ultrasonic">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose> <!-- Adjust the pose as needed -->
    <ray>
      <scan>
        <horizontal>
          <samples>1</samples> <!-- Number of samples -->
          <resolution>1</resolution> <!-- Resolution of the scan -->
          <min_angle>-0.5</min_angle> <!-- Minimum angle of the scan -->
          <max_angle>0.5</max_angle> <!-- Maximum angle of the scan -->
        </horizontal>
      </scan>
      <range>
        <min>0.02</min> <!-- Minimum range (meters) -->
        <max>10.0</max> <!-- Maximum range (meters) -->
        <resolution>0.01</resolution> <!-- Range resolution -->
      </range>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_ray_sensor" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
      <ros>
        <namespace>/</namespace>
        <remapping>~/out:=ultrasonic</remapping>
      </ros>
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <robotNamespace>/my_robot</robotNamespace> <!-- Namespace for the ROS topics -->
      <topicName>/ultrasonic</topicName> <!-- ROS topic to publish data -->
      <updateRate>50</updateRate> <!-- Update rate in Hz -->
      <frameName>sensor_link</frameName> <!-- Frame of reference for the sensor -->
      <radiation_type>ultrasound</radiation_type>
      <output_type>sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan</output_type>
      <minRange>0.02</minRange> <!-- Minimum measurable distance (meters) -->
      <maxRange>10.0</maxRange> <!-- Maximum measurable distance (meters) -->
      <rayCount>1</rayCount> <!-- Number of rays emitted by the sensor -->
      <rangeResolution>0.01</rangeResolution> <!-- Resolution of distance measurements -->
      <noise>0.01</noise> <!-- Optional: adds noise to the sensor readings -->
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>


</robot>

I tried this code and my gazebo sensor plugin should have worked but it is not.
